# express project prints "linux is NOT supported" without explanation

Tags: node.js, linux, express

I have built a NodeJS express project on windows environment, and it running without any problems.

After I have finished I tried uploading the project to a Linux server to run.

Somewhy, after running "npm start" command, the project prints a new line which says:

"linux is NOT supported"

As you can see here:

[image: screenshot of error]

I have tried searching with visual studio in entire project for this string but couldn't find which module does that problem.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base64topdf": "^1.1.8",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "csv-parse": "^2.5.0",
    "csv-parser": "^1.12.1",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "iconv-lite": "^0.4.23",
    "image-to-base64": "^1.3.5",
    "json2csv": "^4.1.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "node-xlsx": "^0.12.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pdf-image": "^2.0.0",
    "pdf-poppler": "^0.2.1",
    "pdf2img": "^0.5.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Can you help me find what module does not supported?

Or maybe the solution is not the one I am thinking of?

Comment: You aren't showing any of your code, not gonna be easy to debug without that. Have you tried removing some of those dependencies and seeing which one may be triggering that message (if it's not you)?

Comment: The thing is I don't know in which part of the project the problem appears and showing the entire project is not an option, of course, therefore there is no code to show. However, I succeeded in solving the problem like I said in the answer.

Answer (score 8):

After doing a long research for each of the dependencies and after trying to remove each of them separately, it turns out that '**pdf-poppler**' was the one that doesn't support Linux.